# Convert temperature data from sensor to celsius degree

Tags: arduino, sensors, stm32, temperature

I have a sensor named LSM303DLHC ,it have 2 temp register but I can't figure it out how to convert it to degrees Celsius.
2 Reg is:

> ```
>     TEMP_OUT_H_M register  // high reg
> ```
>
> TEMP11 | TEMP10 | TEMP9 | TEMP8 | TEMP7 | TEMP6 | TEMP5 | TEMP4
>
> ```
>      TEMP_OUT_L_M register  //low reg
> ```
>
> TEMP3 | TEMP2 | TEMP1 | TEMP0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

In datasheet say: "TEMP[11:0] Temperature data (8 LSB/deg - 12-bit resolution)"
My current code is

```
uint8_t hig_reg = read(TEMP_OUT_H_M)  // value = 0x03
uint8_t low_reg = read(TEMP_OUT_L_M)  // value = 0x40
int16_t temp = ((uint16_t)hig_reg  << 8) | (uint16_t)low_reg;  // temp = 0x0340 = 832

float mTemp = temp/256;  // = 3.25 
mTemp = mTemp +20  ;      // =23.25 (°C)  i add 20 more
```

But I don't understand where the 20 °C offset comes from? Datasheet never mentions it.

Comment: here is Datasheet:
http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/56/ec/ac/de/28/21/4d/48/DM00027543.pdf/files/DM00027543.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00027543.pdf

Comment: One extra implementation detail--The datasheet mentions that the values are reported in [two's complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), so the most significant bit tells you whether it is negative (1) or positive (0).

Comment: Also see : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219032/how-to-determine-temperature-with-lsm303dlhc

Comment: But my value still < 2^11 (2048) .so it still positive value and i dont need to change it. My question is what is the right formula ?

Comment: Can you measure the room temperature with an other device? So do you know what output you should exactly have?

Answer (score 2):

Thank for your answer. Turn out that temperature sensor just determine comparative temperature to calculate the variation. It not use for absolute temperature.They should add that information in datasheet. I just waste 2 day of my life for that.

Comment: Sorry for tour loss :-(. I've read about 20 articles all are discussing about GPS and just afew from temp ...

Answer (score 1):

My try...
First, I have note that you are taking the whole 8 bit TEMP_OUT_L_M register and as you described is just the first 4 bits of it.
Then try to make the 12 bit register first. I use python ans SMBus library,

```
temph = i2cbus.read_byte_data(i2caddress, TEMP_OUT_H_M) << 4 
templ = i2cbus.read_byte_data(i2caddress, TEMP_OUT_L_M) >> 4
tempread = temph + templ   # it is all ready converted to Decimal
```

Then you can go ahead with the transformation: see page 11 title 2.2 "Temperature sensor characteristics: 8 LSB/ºC , 12 bit resolution and 2.5 Vdd."

Then it is clear that:

```
ºC = (read_value * VDD * 10^(log 2 (LSB/ºC)) / ((resolution - 1) * (10*(ºC/LSB))
```

In the LSM303 then following the python code:

```
# temperature = (tempread * 2.5 * 1000)/(2^12-1) * (10/8))  better to write:
temperature = (tempread *2500)/(4095 * 1.25)
```

In your case: you have read: 0x0340, in 12 bits 0x34 in decimal: 54

```
temperature = (54 * 2500) / (4095 * 1.25) = 23.443223
```

I also noticed that:

- The maximum  secure register to read is 85ºC = 0x55, so we better make the register with the 4 bit LSB of TEMP_OUT_H_M and 4 bit MSB of TEMP_OUT_L_M.
- In further test the LSM303 can resist near 125 ºC for a while, with out permanent damage, but it a good practice to use this temperature to put the Magnetometer and Accelerometer in a sleep mode. When the temperature reaches 80.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that TEMP is on 10 bits and one for the sign (value max you can read : 0x3FF), so:

> 0x03FF - 0x0340 = 0x0BF
>
> 0x0BF / 8 = 0x17 (23.875 in decimal).

As said, don't forget the two's complement in your computation.

Comment: i dont think your formula is right. 0x0340 (823) still < 2^11 (2048) . so dont need to use '-'. Beside when i touch the sensor , value increase to 0x05e0.

Comment: You can eventually check : https://github.com/embeddedadventures/BME280/blob/master/BME280_MOD-1022.cpp

Comment: And this thread : https://forum.pololu.com/t/16-bit-values-in-lsm303/8499

Comment: The whole data is 12 bits itself so 1+10 bit seems 1 bit short. The `0x340` actually should be `0x34` the last 4 bit are not part of the temperature data.